# ¿Cómo hacer una calculadora de presupuesto con JS?

Tags: javascript, lógica

Estoy haciendo una calculadora de presupuesto con JS.

Lo que hace es ingresas una cantidad y te va dando el ahorro, lo que gastas y lo que gastarías.

Pero al momento de sacar el ahorro anual no me marca nada.

La formula sería:

totalan - totalanvit

https://codepen.io/luis-uribe/pen/qBEVpYR

```js
    function calcular(){
    //Obtienes el valor
     var valor = document.getElementById("valor").value;

     var result= document.getElementById('result');
     var total= document.getElementById('total');
     var totalan = document.getElementById('totalan');

     var totalanvit = document.getElementById('totalanvit');
     var ahanul = document.getElementById('ahanul')



    //le descuentas el 95% y lo agregas al HTML
     var descuento = parseInt(valor)*0.95;
     var totalanual = parseInt(valor) * 365;


     //agrega los resultados al DOM
    result.innerHTML = 'Ahorro de: $' + descuento;
    total.innerHTML =  'Tu nuevo recibo bimestral:     $' + (parseInt(valor)- 
     descuento);
    totalan.innerHTML = 'Lo que pagabas antes de vitoenergy en 1 año $' + 
    totalanual;
    totalanvit.innerHTML = 'Lo que pagarias con vitoenergy en 1 año $' + 
    (parseInt(valor)-descuento) * 365;

     //Aqui es donde ya no marca nada
     ahanul.innerHTML = 'Tu ahorro anual $' + parseInt(totalan - totalanvit);
  
    }
```

```html
     <h1> Ingrese su consumo mensual:</h1>
    <input id="valor" type="number" onkeyUp="calcular();">
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id="result"></span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id="total"></span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id="totalan"></span>
    <br><br>
    <span id="totalanvit"></span>
    <br><br>
    <span id="ahanul"></span>
```

No se si se me está pasando poner algo o la lógica está mal.

Saludos

Comment: Por favor pon aquí el código, si ese codepen se borra, la pregunta quedaría incompleta.

Comment: `descuento` es de tipo string cuando intentas sumar numero y cadena te dara Not a Number te recomiendo transformar los numeros a entero y luego hacer las operaciones matematicas que deseas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu fórmula deberías de poner:

```
ahanul.innerHTML = 'Tu ahorro anual $' + parseInt(totalanual - (parseInt(valor)-descuento) * 365);
```